Research Faculty with no salary
I was a postdoc for two year and promoted to research assistant professor this month. Although my supervisor strongly convinced me to stay with him and always came up with long term plans, he could not bring any funding to support my salary and told me (just two weeks before starting the new semester) to seek teaching opportunities within our department. But as I talked to the department head, he did not guarantee that there will be any teaching position available as all of them are already filled.
I am not a green card holder nor citizen, so I cannot apply for jobs outside of the university because the change of visa status can take up to a year.
I should also mention that finding an equivalent position at other universities may also be challenging since the hiring process of assistant professors are usually time taking if I am lucky enough to find an opening.
Please kindly correct me if I am wrong and let me know if you have thoughts that may help me survive at least for the next semester until I find a new position.
Thank you!

Yikes! You are not being treated well, I would say! I think your appraisal of the difficulties is correct, and I have no good advice. You can still hope that the department does come up with some teaching openings, after they see enrollment figures for the upcoming semester. The dept head saying they cannot guarantee is surely just honest... though, the dept might want to compensate for your supervisor's negligence!

Does your supervisor know what departmend head shared with you on a lack of guarantee of a teaching position? If not, then I would inform your supervisor and expect him to find a way to get research salary in the case of force majeure.

Does your visa not depend on having a paid job ?

How good are you at writing grant proposals?

What's your question?

Can someone in the US comment on whether this is legal? In Australia, it wouldn’t be, and there are protections in place for people who report employers that abuse their visa vulnerability to underpay (though an unpaid visiting researcher position would probably be legal if the visa allowed them to stay without work).

What country are you in? What kind of visa do you have?

@Significance It's legal if when he doesn't get paid, he doesn't have responsibilities. He's free to return to his home country. Does Australia guarantee permanent market-rate employment to everybody on a visa?

I think you should move on and find other jobs. Your supervisor does not seem very considerate of your visa situation. I would not trust his long-term plans if he is unable to solve the short-term funding problem.

But OP says "I cannot apply for jobs outside of the university" -- please explain how to get around this.

He may apply to jobs in other countries.

This is for sure an awkward position you find yourself in. I'm not sure any of us can provide any useful feedback; I see nothing inherently incorrect in your description of the situation. At many universities, research faculty positions like the one you've been promoted into are indeed "soft money positions", i.e., all salary comes from external grants.
I think it might be useful to ask yourself how you ended up here. The fact that the position is not funded by the university other than through external grants should have been something you should have been aware of a long time ago, along with the need to have contingency plans should there not be any external funding through your PI. If you were unaware of this fact, then you did not do your homework in learning about the position you were about to accept, and your adviser did not appropriately communicate with you either. The fact that you are only considering alternatives such a short time before the semester starts means that something fundamental has gone wrong.

Soft money positions have terrible job security. What it does allow one to do, as opposed to being a postdoc, depending on the agency, is be a lead PI for grants. So it can be a good way to start ones career if they are unable to secure a traditional tenure-track role. But as you say, something has gone awfully wrong that OP has accepted this position and failed to secure funding for it, whether through their advisor or on their own. Also it appears as though this is not a true research assistant professor position (i.e. more independent), but rather an extended postdoc with their former PI.
